# Seeing if comment in cell is null using Excel interlop c#.net

Tags: c#, excel

Hey all I am using the code below in order to find out if a cell in the Excel sheet that I am parsing thru has a comment or not.

```
int columnCount = ws.UsedRange.Columns.Count;
Dictionary<string,bool> storedValidaters = new Dictionary<string, bool>();

for (int c = 1; c < columnCount; c++)
{
   if (ws.Cells[2, c].Comment.Shape.AlternativeText != null)
   {
      string columnName = ws.Cells[2, c].Value2.ToString();
      string myComment = ws.Cells[2, c].Comment.Shape.AlternativeText.ToString().Replace("Text Box: ", "");

      storedValidaters.Add(columnName, true);
   } else {
      //the value is null so its false
      string columnName = ws.Cells[2, c].Value2.ToString();

      storedValidaters.Add(columnName, false);
   }
}
```

It loops a few times but once it gets to a cell that **does not have** a comment, it poops.

[image]

Having the error of **Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference**.

I did a few searches to find out if anyone else had working code in order to check for *null* but have been unable to find a working example.

Anyone know of a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend changing:

```
Comment.Shape.AlternativeText
```

to:

```
Comment?.Shape?.AlternativeText
```

The [null conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators) will ensure that the code will continue to work as expected regardless of whether the `Comment` is null, or the `Shape` is null or the `AlternativeText` is null.